# Transfering dates from python to r with reticulates

Tags: r, reticulate

I'm using reticulate package to write r and python.
When I create dates variable in python and load them in r, with reticulate package, the dates are different.

for example:

```
as.POSIXct(py_to_r(r_to_py(as.POSIXct("2020-01-04 06:05:00"))))
```

will give me: `"2020-01-04 04:05:00 UTC"`

we can see that the hours that comes from python into r are two hours different.

Comment: They should describe the same time point. One is probably in local time zone and the other is in UTC time zone. That's why only the hour differs.

Comment: Probably you live UTC+2?

Comment: @Quinten how i fix it in python?